# Update ObservableList with data from sorted list?

Tags: javafx

I have followed this [1](http://code.makery.ch/blog/javafx-8-tableview-sorting-filtering/#) tutorial to create a tableview with filtering. It works great, but the code in the tutorial creates a new SortedList (sortedData) with the sorted data and binds it with comparotorproperty to the table view, which originally uses a ObservableList as data source.

```
SortedList<Record> sortedData = new SortedList<Record>(filteredData);
// 4. Bind the SortedList comparator to the TableView comparator.
    sortedData.comparatorProperty().bind(tableView.comparatorProperty());

    // 5. Add sorted (and filtered) data to the table.
    tableView.setItems(sortedData);
```

In my code I also have a Pie Chart and Bar Chart. They also use the ObservableList as data sources, so my question is ; how can I bind the sortedData to the ObservableList?

My code to get the data to the PieChart (and BarChart) is this:

```
 for (Record record : dataen) {
        dataList.add(new PieChart.Data(record.getFieldMonth(), record.getFieldValue()));
    }
```

Where record is a class with Getters and Setters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to turn `ObservableList<Record>` into `ObservableList<PieChart.Data>`, correct? For that you can use [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind):

```
ObservableList<PieChart.Data> chartData = EasyBind.map(sortedData,
        r -> new PieChart.Data(r.getFieldMonth(), r.getFieldValue()));

pieChart.setData(chartData);
```

Comment: I actually first thought of updating observableList<Record> with the sortedData.. But if easybind works with barchart aswell(?) I am happy !

Comment: Your `sortedData` already is `ObservableList<Record>`. Do you for some reason have to stick with your particular `ObservableList<Record>` instance and cannot replace it by `sortedData`? If that is the case, then use `EasyBind.listBind(recordList, sortedData)`. This will keep `recordList` in sync with `sortedData`.

Comment: I do not need to stick with it. But how would I get the new sortedData in the barchart and piechart ? I previously used the record.getFieldMonth and the same for value. I guess my basic question is how I can use the data from the gridview(the sorted one) to populate the different visualizations, for example barchart or pie

Comment: That's what my original answer does---uses sortedData to populate a pie chart.

Comment: @miniHeessel Which part exactly throws `NullPointerException`?